# Modifies clause error on a changed object

Tags: automated-tests, verification, solidity, dafny

How can I state (in Dafny) an "*ensures*" guarantee that the object returned by a method will be "new", i.e., will not be the same as an object used anywhere else (yet)?

The following code shows a minimal example:

```
method newArray(a:array<int>) returns (b:array<int>)
requires a != null
ensures b != null
ensures a != b
ensures b.Length == a.Length+1
{
  b := new int[a.Length+1];
}

class Testing {
  var test : array<int>;

  method doesnotwork()
  requires this.test!=null
  requires this.test.Length > 10;
  modifies this
  {
    this.test := newArray(this.test); //change array a with b
    this.test[3] := 9;  //error modifies clause
  }

  method doeswork()
  requires this.test!=null
  requires this.test.Length > 10;
  modifies this
  {
    this.test := new int[this.test.Length+1];
    this.test[3] := 9;
  }


}
```

The "*doeswork*" function compiles (and verifies) correctly, but the other one does not, as the Dafny compiler cannot know that the object returned by the "*newArray*" function is new, i.e., is not required to be listed as modifiable in the "require" statement of the "*doesnotwork*" function in order for that function to fulfill the requirement that it only modifies "*this*". In the "*doeswork*" function, I simply inserted the definition of the "*newArray*" function, and then it works.

You can find the example above under https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/hHWwr, where it can also be ran online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say `ensures fresh(b)` on `newArray`.

`fresh` means exactly what you described: the object is not the same as any object that was allocated before the call to `newArray`.