# How can I tell Dafny that a method always returns a `new` object?

Tags: arrays, verification, dafny

[In this example](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Lg9t), I have a method that returns a new array:

```
method Zeroes(len: nat) returns (h: array<nat>)
  ensures h.Length == len && all_zeroes(h)
{
  h := new nat[len];
  ...
}
```

and another method that tries to use it:

```
method Histogram(a: array<nat>, limit: nat) returns (h: array<nat>)
  requires greater_than_all(limit, a)
  ensures h.Length == limit && histogram_of(h, a)
{
  h := Zeroes(limit);
  assert histogram_of_prefix(h, a, 0);

  var i := 0;
  while i < a.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
    invariant histogram_of_prefix(h, a, i)
  {
    var n := a[i];
    h[n] := h[n] + 1;
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Dafny complains because it can't prove that `Zeroes(limit)` won't return `a`. (If it ever did, my code would be completely broken, Dafny rightly points out.)

It appears that by factoring out `Zeroes` into a function, I've taken away some information. If I move the body of `Zeroes` back into `Histogram`, then Dafny sees `h := new nat[limit];` it knows that's not the same array as `a`, and verification succeeds.

**How can I change the signature of `Zeroes` to tell Dafny that it always returns a new array?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fresh` for that. As in

```
ensures fresh(h)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47590811/438267).